# Crate dependency cylce when using optional dependencies

Tags: rust, dependencies, rust-crates, rust-futures

I have two crate which need functions from each other. I know this is bad practice, but is there a way to do this?

I made two crate with the following configs:
for crate A:

```
[dependencies]
B = {path = "./../B", features = [], optional = true}

[features]
default = ["flag"]
flag = ["dep:B"]
```

and for crate B:

```
[dependencies]
A = {path = "./../A", features = [], optional = true}

[features]
default = ["flag"]
flag = ["dep:A"]
```

But this still give me a cyclic package dependency error.
Did i do the features setup wrong?

As extra context, i am trying to make a sudo-webframework. The idea is that one crate is build like normal and that the other one is build using trunk. I have some features and macros setup to turn marked methods into either themself or a sending a tcp packet with the arguments. The goal is to not have the api of a function defined in multiple places.

Comment: You cannot have cyclic dependency between crates. Either make them one crate or extract the common functionality into its own crate.

Comment: How could I combine them and also have 2 different entry points?

Comment: You can use a feature to decide (via `#[cfg]`) which entry point to activate. Or you can just use different crates which common functionality in a shared crate. Or use one crate and other two crates for the entry points.

Comment: You could try refactoring into a [workspace](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-03-cargo-workspaces.html), with a private lib member holding implementation details, and multiple entry point binary members.